# Image Fit and Positioning Compatibility Across Browsers

Tags: css, image, cross-browser

I have created an html/javascript/css page which displays photos in a "carousel", where the user can click the left and right arrows to change the photo.  The carousel itself, the parent/container, is 500px tall and 100% of its parent div wide.  The image inside of it should be at max 100% wide and at max 100% tall.  In other words, it will fit itself into the imgCarousel, regardless of aspect ratio.

This works in most browsers.  I have confirmed that it works in IE, Edge, Chrome, and Firefox.  However, it does not work in Safari.  I don't personally have access to a Mac, but I know it does not work in Safari because others have viewed the page before me.  It also does not work in some android mobile browsers (though it does work with Android Chrome).

It appears that in these browsers where it does not work, the top is not actually set to 50%, but that the transform is still working properly.  This is based on visual inspection.  In addition, it appears that the image is not being sized properly.  It is extending to the full width, and the height is extending beyond 100%;

Unfortunately, I cannot test with developer tools on any of these browsers, since I don't have access to a Mac, and I can't seem to find developer tools for mobile browsers that can be used in the same capacity.

I can link to the page in question if it is not a breach of protocol here.

I have done some research to see if there are any compatability issues/fixes, but I have not been successful in this research.  If anyone knows of any way I can include a compatibility fix, please let me know.

Thank you.

```
.imgCarousel {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;

    vertical-align: middle;

    height: 500px;
    background-color: black;
    text-align: center;
    margin: auto;
}

.imgCarousel img {
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);

    max-height: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    object-fit: contain;

    cursor: pointer;

}
```

Comment: Could you post a demo of the carousel in JSfiddle, CodePen, a snippet? Or just a link to the website?

Comment: You can install safari on your windows box.

Comment: You might be missing the browser prefixes for those browsers for the `transform` property.

Comment: Also make sure their safari is up to date. Its not uncommon for me to find out a user has an ancient version of safari. If so it probably doesn't support some of these css properties. You should also put properties you know work higher in your declaration because some parsers stop parsing the declaration when they hit an error.

Comment: The link to the website is here: [link](http://brandonquinndixon.com/photos.html) .  Also, it looks like the windows version of Safari is no longer supported.  When I downloaded from a 3rd party location, many of the more modern html and css components were non-functional.

Comment: Either chrome or FF on IOS should reproduce the issue if it's related to safari.

Comment: If you mean to say that Chrome on iOS should also have the same issue, it does not.  The person who tested it for me sent me screenshots of Safari and Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this list, including the opera prefix:

```
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
    -moz-transform: translateY(-50%);
    -o-transform: translateY(-50%);
```

Comment: Thanks.  I have made the adjustment.  Unfortunately, it has not solved the problem (at least on the mobile phone), but it is good to include in the code, nonetheless.  I cannot confirm on Safari.